# Keynote on the iPad does not to the projector (VGA output)?

Tags: ipad, keynote, vga-adapter, projector

On an iPad, when we hit play for a Keynote presentation while connected to a projector via VGA cable, the app closes down.

What tricks are there for getting iPad-Keynote to work with a projector?

Comment: If possible, try using the VGA cable to hook the iPad up to a regular monitor. Does that give you the same result?

Comment: I have the same problum. I am tryingt o do a presentation for school and my ipad dosnt even look teh same as most on even youtube. The slides will play perfectly through keynote, but only when its not connected to the vga adapter. WHY! I can get the frist slide to work then when I move to the second slide, keynote crashes.

Comment: This isn't really an answer, please move it to the comments section of the original question.

Comment: Nilloc is right, delete the question and make it a comment on the question, or if you tried the checkmarked answer and it didn't work, start a new question and explain that this didn't work.

Comment: Welcome to the community. Stackexchange is not like other forums. Answers to questions should actually attempt to answer the question. Otherwise, remarks such as this should be entered as a comment. I am going to convert your answer to a comment for the question itself. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we called Apple they said we need to re-set the iPad

Comment: For those who don't know how to restart an iPad: **press and hold the power button** until "Slide to power off" appears, and slide it. After it's done shutting down, press and hold the power button until it starts up again. This should solve the problem. To completely reset it (this will lose data so back up first), open the **Settings app**, choose **General**, then **Reset**, then either **Reset All Settings** or, if absolutely necessary (this will restore your iPad to factory settings, erasing everything), **Erase All Content and Settings**.

Answer (score 0):

It might be the file: have you tried another presentation? It may have altered in some way during the translation such that it displays ok on the device but fails when output.

Is the projector you're connecting to 1024 x 768? I've had it work with a projector of another size, but it only sends an image that size. It's not likely, but perhaps there's a VGA sync issue that's crashing the app.

Comment: @Mathew Frederick --- yes the app is crashing. So your 'VGA sync issue' sounds good. But I am not sure how to tell if the projector is 1024 x 768 --- any further suggestions would be great...... ( we have a presentation tomorrow about iPad apps tomorrow -- yikes )

Comment: Well, you could hook a laptop to the projector and use it's Display preferences/control panel to see the display size of the projector. I'll say that I've had iPad Keynote output work great a few times now, so I know it's possible.

Answer (score -1):

Turn off the iPad (shut down) and then turn it on again. It worked for me.